# Should the SessionID in the QueryString or the Cookie of a GET request take precedence?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, session, security, httprequest

If I receive a request to the url `host.com/site-directory/page-slug.html?session={someValidNonExpiredSessionGuid}` and I detect a session cookie with the value: `{someOtherValidNonExpiredSessionGuid}`, then

### Which session is the correct session to associate with the request?

Here's some background:

The pattern I am using for maintaining state across HTTP requests is to store a unique ID in the querystring, form collection and/or cookie.  Then, on each request, I locate the unique Id and pull date from a database table.  If the id is not valid, or the session is expired, a new session will be created (with a new id, a new cookie, etc).

The default behavior is that all forms will have a field:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="session" value="{someGuid}" />
```

All links to other pages on the site will have an appended querystring parameter

```
 <a href="site-directory/page-slug.html?session={someGuid}">a sample link</a>
```

And, if the user's browsing device supports cookies, a cookie will be set having the session's value.

If I have validated that the user's browsing device supports cookies, then my form and querystring will no longer require the the session id field/parameter.

However, I am having a conceptual issue in deciding whether the session parameter of the querystring should take precedence over the cookie value or vice-versa.  It seems like I could potentially get bad data in either circumstance.  I could get data with a bad querystring parameter if the user bookmarked a page with the session parameter included in the URL.  I could also get bad data from the cookie, if a user closes the browser without terminating the session, and the session expire-window has not yet closed.  It also seems like both options could be vulnerable to a malicious user intercepting the request and sending a request with the same session information.

### So, once again, my question is

If I receive a request to the url `host.com/site-directory/page-slug.html?session={someValidNonExpiredSessionGuid}` and I detect a session cookie with the value: `{someOtherValidNonExpiredSessionGuid}`, then **Which session is the correct session to associate with the request?**

I am leaning towards the cookie session, because it seems like the most common scenario will be a bookmark with the session included.  I've already decided that the form post data should take the greatest precedence, because a page will always render the form with the correct ID, and the only possible situation with a wrong, non-expired ID is a very quickly implemented XSS attack, which is circumvented by including a request-scoped anti-forgery token field.

**In addition to the primary question I appreciate any insight to any security-related or logical oversights I have expressed in this description.**  I apologize for the long post, but felt it was necessary to explain the situation.  Thank you very much for your input.

Also, it is not necessarily relevant to the question, but I am using ASP.NET MVC in most situations, and setting my cookies manually with `Response.Cookies`.

Comment: I confuse. Why did you realize so difficult solution? What sessionstate store do u use: inproce, memcache, db or something else?

Comment: @Antony Blazer, using ASP.NET's SessionState is an implementation detail.  My question is conceptual and applicable to any HTTP application.

Answer (score 1):

From a security standpoint sessions should not be stored in query strings.

For example:
If sessions are stored in queries and you link to a remote host on the same page, the users valid session could be sent to the remote host via the referer header.

Sessions should always be stored in cookies.

Comment: Your contention that "sessions should always be stored in cookies" seems highly problematic in situations where browsers either don't support cookies or have cookies turned off.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to store it in the cookie (looking the the browser caps to see if the browser supports cookies) and then have a fall back for query string.

Answer (score 0):

I too would lean towards using the cookie session ID in case of ambiguity.  This primarily because I'd trust the cookie implementation to be more well baked, more well tested, and more idiot-proof than my own home brewed session tracking implementation.   For e.g. there are cases where ASP.NET automatically knows to clear the session cookies, renew them etc.

Also, I would design it so the cookies aren't persistent to minimize the edge cases.  If the user closes the browser, then the session is closed.

The other simplification I would consider is to have either cookies or URL based tracking and not both.   If the browser supports cookies, there is really no reason to also track the session through a URL.

Thoughts?

Curious ... What were your reason to rule out using the stock ASP.NET cookieless session implementation? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx#cookieless_topic2

Comment: because not all environments support the ASP.NET lifecycle.  Today I'm using ASP.NET MVC, but tomorrow I might not have access to that, so I want to know the fundamentals.

Comment: Also, The problem with your simplification is in the first request.  You can't know conclusively that a browser correctly supports cookies until you have tried to set the cookie on one request and retrieved in on a consequent request.  So, any links that are rendered prior to that validation need to include the session in the url.

Comment: True.  I've seen implementations implementations that attempt to set a cookie with a HTTP redirect when the user first visits the site, to see if the cookie comes back.  There are some edge cases I can think of with that approach,  but overall  - from what I recall - it worked reliably.

Answer (score 0):

> If I receive a request to the url
>   host.com/site-directory/page-slug.html?session={someValidNonExpiredSessionGuid}
>   and I detect a session cookie with the
>   value:
>   {someOtherValidNonExpiredSessionGuid},
>   then Which session is the correct
>   session to associate with the request?

To answer your specific question, I'd recommend putting session management in the cookies as opposed to the querystring.  As has been mentioned, cookies can be set to expire whereas the querystring cannot.  This allows your thin-clients to assist in their own session maintenance by removing their own expired cookies.  Moreover, since cookies are dropped to specific browsers, you reduce the chances of another browser spoofing the original browser session.

The only way I would use the querystring to pass session information would be as a backup method to re-establish a browser session onto a new browser instance.  Here's a scenario: you have an active session using browser A on machine A which suffers some catastrophic error. You want a way to re-establish that same session on another browser instance on either the same machine or on another machine.  If your code-behind can recognize that the session cookie doesn't exist, but that a valid session id exists in the querystring, you *could* initiate a challenge-response to verify the integrity of that session id and then drop a new session cookie on the new machine.  Kinda extreme in my humble opinion, but the functionality might be useful in certain situations.

ADDED:  I understand that you may want to accommodate users who have turned cookies off on their browsers, and while you *can* use the querystring to hold the session id I'd recommend against it.  But if you must, encrypt that sucker using browser-machine specific information.